# RDD split reverse of groupByKey

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

Right now i've a file contains

```
1: 3 4
2: 1 3 5
```

i'd like to make it into

```
1: 3
1: 4
2: 1
2: 3
2: 5
```

it's like a reverse version of groupByKey
anyone have idea how to solve that?
Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the `flatMap` method.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Answer (score 2):

You can explode the list using `flatMapValues`:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1, Seq(4, 5)),
  (2, Seq(1, 3, 5))
))

rdd.flatMapValues(x => x).collect
// res1: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((1,4), (1,5), (2,1), (2,3), (2,5))
```

If the data is in a text file, create a RDD first.  For example:

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("/path/to/file").
  map(_.split(": ")).
  map{ case Array(x, y) => (x, y.split(" ")) }
```